# Sql syntax error 1064 for a stored procedure when adding the INNER JOIN and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

Im getting this syntax error 1064 near Inner join users u on u.id = ub.user_id WHERE u.active =0 AND IFNULL ' at line 2.
Also, what's the best way to debug a stored procedure??

```
Expected Output : delete data for not active users
```

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE `logdb_user_breaks_delete`(

IN log_database VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, 

IN retention_logdb INT(11) )

BEGIN SET @v = concat('DELETE FROM `',log_database ,'`.`user_breaks` ub
INNER JOIN users u on u.id = ub.user_id

WHERE u.active = 0 AND

IFNULL(ub.updated_at, ub.inserted_at) < (CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), "-", MONTH(NOW()), "-

", "01") - INTERVAL ',retention_logdb,' MONTH);');

PREPARE stm FROM @v;

EXECUTE stm; 

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: By trying to write the code beautifully, you have made it incorrect. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88fba51b58d3f8018897e99775b04d70

Comment: `CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), "-", MONTH(NOW()), "-", "01")` can be replaced with more clear `DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01')`. And this expression uses 2 fn calls instead of 5.

Comment: Hello @akina im still getting the same error I tried the code under built sql code

Comment: Create a fiddle with your structures, data and SQL code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you  for the help.May I ask what's the easiest way to debug the stored procedure im currently using heidi im still not familliar with it.

Comment: I don't know if there are tricks for debugging; it does help to only put sql in the stored procedure after testing to make sure it works.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join tables, you have to indicate which tables you are trying to delete.  I'm guessing you want to delete the user_breaks rows, not the users rows.  Change `DELETE FROM` to `DELETE ub FROM`.

Comment: I tried it and im getting an error unknown table 'ub' in multi delete? Thanks

Comment: @Stella your shown code clearly does: ``DELETE FROM `',log_database ,'`.`user_breaks` ub`` giving the user_breaks table a ub alias.  Did you change that?  Please run your SET command (replacing the parameters with the values you are passing) and show what @v is set to.

Comment: this shows it working, with the only changes from your pasted code adding the `ub` between DELETE and FROM and removing the extra lines in the second "-": https://dbfiddle.uk/sPCKf0CZ